# Referencement issue with irrelevant suffix

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot

I have a problem concerning the "coverage" on Google Search Console. The website of the company I'm working for has weird errors on this page. Google is telling that it had issues referencing pages with an odd URL like you can see above :

http://www.rbs-france.fr/fr/assembleuse.php?ACF-510SOLO_+A+STAR+WARS+STORY+Extended+TV+Spot+Trailer+2018+Donald+Glover+Sci-Fi+MoEge+Kalbimdeki+A
http://www.rbs-france.fr/fr/agrafeuse_manuelle.php?B40/4.Grapadora+Stanley+FMHT6-70868+TR75+Grapadora+6+en+1https://www.amazon.es/Stanley-FMHT6-70868-TR75-Grapadora/dp/B00975VA12/ref=sr_1_10?s=tools&ie=UTF8&qid=1480319901&sr=1-10&keywords=grapadora+cables.21+Ways+to+Hide+and+Organize+Things+in+your+House+
http://www.rbs-france.fr/fr/Thermorelieur_Fastback_Planax.php?FB-9-E-La+replica+della+Seredova+su+Twitter+e+fbLa
http://www.rbs-france.fr/fr/destructeur_document_personnel.php?Securio-C18-1.9x15Dragon+Ball+Fighterz+VEGETA+62+HIT+COMBO+AND+C18+73+HIT+COMBOHope
After looking at these URLs, I noticed that the concerned pages are products currently online on the company's website and an irrelevant suffix. I tried to reproduce this error but I couldn't. For most of the errors, I've seen that the suffix concerns videos. I don't know why these URLs have such irrelevant suffixes and how it happened. I tried to search on the Internet but I couldn't find anyone with an issue like mine.

If someone here knows a way to understand or to solve my problem, I'll be very thankful!

Comment: Google says in Search Console where it found those URLs.  What does Google say?

Comment: It says nothing much. Referring page "None detected", Crawled as "Googlebot smartphone", Page fetch "Failed: Crawl anomaly"